# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions

Tags: eclipse, ant, noclassdeffounderror

I am working as an eclipse plugin developer and when I try to build my eclipse sources from command line using ant, it fails with following error.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions

I am using java 1.7_72, eclipse 44, ant 1.7.1

It was working with this configuration for long time on my machine, and it suddenly started failing with this message. I have tried various options like uninstalling and reinstalling all the possible software that could affect, gone for fresh copy of eclipse, ant and much more.
It works on my colleagues machine and we all use the same software eclipse/ant/java etc.
Any inputs are welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have an old copy of ecj.jar lying around in your classpath somewhere?  Perhaps in the ext library?

Comment: No, there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with similar error using Eclipse's PDE headless product build scripts.

The error occurs when the builder executes a temporary `build.xml` file that it generated for my plugin. this build file compiles my plugin code.

trying to run this temporary build file manually with ant on the command line works though.

Obviously, the error suggests an issue with the JDT compiler.

Looking at the generated `build.xml`, I found out the following target:

```
<target name="properties" if="eclipse.running">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
</target>
```

which tells the builder to override the default JDK compiler when the property `eclipse.running` is `true`.

I added

```
<property name="eclipse.running" value="false"/>
```

at the beginning of my build script: the error disappeared and my build completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue also appeared during PDE headless build with Eclipse Neon. The build script property (`baseLocation`) was pointing to a running instance of Eclipse. 
Closing Eclipse before running the build resolved the issue.

The issue appeared after an update of the Target Platform. It ended up to include a newer version of Eclipse and JDT in addition to installed version.

It showed up again after update from Eclipse Neon to 2019-03 (4.14). Adding the `-data <workspace>"` to the eclipse launcher command-line solved it.